# PHP HTML Filter Feature

Tags: php, html

What would be the best way to create a filter feature in PHP so the user can select which records they want displayed in a table.

For example, a database of addresses. I want to add a feature so the user can select which county they want displayed in a table (A filter feature).

I plan to just run a `for each` to loop through each of the rows and add the county to a checkbox group so then the user can check which of the counties they want to be displayed then I can base my MySQL query on that but I figures it would take time especially since I'd be having 5000 or more records.

What would be the most convenient way to achieve this and is there a command or a feature in PHP to get all the unique values in a column so I can list them in the filter box?

Comment: the best way is with ajax (reload the page without redirection); and for get all unique values, you can use the requete sql "SELECT DISTINCT your_col FROM your_table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus more on the SQL aspect of the problem. Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;
```

Also, you could make your database such that the countries are foreign keys to another COUNTRY table. this will reduce a huge amount of redundancy as the database is not filled with repeated mentions of same names.

**NOTE:** Never retrieve all the entries from the database and run for each loops, try to retrieve as few rows as possible from the database.

Comment: Thank you, been away for a while. I will test this but it looks like it is what I'm looking for, wasn't aware there's a SELECT DISTINCT command :)